# Bash & blocking processes

Tags: unix, bash, shell, unix-shell

Could you help me with the Bash syntax to achieve the following?

1. Run a blocking process without blocking execution of the rest of the script.
2. Run a standard "non-blocking" process (e.g. lsof).
3. "Rejoin" the blocking process so that ^C will stop that process, then end execution of the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this an idiomatic way to do it?

```
#!/bin/bash
function handle_int()
{
    kill $BCPID
    exit
}
trap handle_int INT

blocking_command &
BCPID=$!

non_blocking_command
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# script
command &
# more script
wait
```

Comment: With that, pressing ^C exits the script, but leaves the blocking process still running, on my system (Mac OS X).